# Apollo/graphql request result buffered in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, graphql, strapi, vue-apollo

In a Vue component controlling users subsciption to newsletters, I have the fellowing code:

```
async newSubscriber(event) {
  // Validate email
  //---------------
  if (!this.isEmailValid(this.subscriber_email))
      this.subscribeResult = "Email not valid";
  else {
    // If valid, check if email is not already recorded
    //-------------------------------------------------
    let alreadyRecorded = false;
    let recordedEmails = await this.$apollo.query({ query: gql`query { newslettersEmails { email } }` });
    console.log('length ' + recordedEmails.data.newslettersEmails.length);
    console.log(recordedEmails.data.newslettersEmails);
    for (let i = 0; !alreadyRecorded && i < recordedEmails.data.newslettersEmails.length; i++)
      alreadyRecorded = this.subscriber_email === recordedEmails.data.newslettersEmails[i].email;
    if (alreadyRecorded)
      this.subscribeResult = "Email already recorded";
    else {
      // If not, record it and warn the user
      //------------------------------------
      this.$apollo.mutate({
        mutation: gql`mutation ($subscriber_email: String!){
          createNewslettersEmail(input: { data: { email: $subscriber_email } }) {
            newslettersEmail {
              email
            }
          }
        }`,
        variables: {
          subscriber_email: this.subscriber_email,
        }
      })
      .then((data) => { this.subscribeResult = "Email recorded"; })
      .catch((error) => { this.subscribeResult = "Error recording the email: " + error.graphQLErrors[0].message; });
    }
  }
}
```

At the very first email subscription test, $apollo.query returns me the correct number of emails already recorded (let's say, 10) and record the new subscriber email. But if I try to record a second email without hard refreshing (F5) the browser, $apollo.query returns me the exact same result than the first time (10), EVEN IF the first test email has been correctly recorded by strapi (graphql palyground showns me the added email with the very same query!). Even if I add ten emails, apollo will always return me what it got during its first call (10 recorded emails), as if it uses a buffered result. Of course, that allows Vue to record several times the same email, which I obviously want to avoid!

Does it speaks to anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of Google digging (giving the desired results by simply changing in my requests, at the end, "buffering" by "caching" !), I understood that Apollo cache its queries by default (at least, in the configuration of the Vue project I received). To solve the problem I just added "fetchPolicy: 'network-only'" to the query I make:

```
let recordedEmails = await this.$apollo.query({
  query: gql`query { newslettersEmails { email } }`,
});
```

became

```
let recordedEmails = await this.$apollo.query({
  query: gql`query { newslettersEmails { email } }`,
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
});
```

And problem solved ^^